# NETBEANS - JAVA - DERBY - Erro ao recuperar byte para ImageIcon

Tags: java, netbeans, cast, byte

Salve galera tudo bom?
Armazenei um arquivo BLOB e estou procurando fazer recuperação do mesmo, é um JPG.

Segue abaixo o ResultSet do mesmo:

```
        byte[] bin = null; // (2)

        ResultSet rs;                
            try {

                rs = produtoControle.escolha(buscar.getText());    
                    while(rs.next()){                            
                        lblNumId.setText(rs.getString("codigo"));
                        tfNome.setText(rs.getString("nome_produto"));
                        cbCategoria.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(rs.getString("categoria")));
                        tfQuantidade.setText(rs.getString("quantidade"));
                        tfPreco.setText(rs.getString("preco"));
                        tfFabDist.setText(rs.getString("fabricante"));
                        tfResponsavel.setText(rs.getString("responsavel"));
                        tftTelefone.setText(rs.getString("telefone"));
                        tfEmail.setText(rs.getString("email"));
                        taInfo.setText(rs.getString("informacoes"));

                        bin = rs.getBytes("imagem");
                    }

                    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bin);
                    Iterator <?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");// (2)

                    ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
                    Object source = bis;
                    ImageInputStream iis; 
            try {
                iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source);
                reader.setInput(iis, true);
                ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
                Image imagem = reader.read(0, param);
                foto.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imagem.getScaledInstance(foto.getWidth(), foto.getHeight(), imagem.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(InterfaceProduto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }                        
                    if("".equals(lblNumId.getText())){
                        fechaConexao();
                        return;
                    }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InterfaceProduto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }   
        ValidaCampos("novo");
           btSalvar.setText("Alterar");
            btExcluir.setEnabled(true);
            fechaConexao();
}
```

E ocorre o seguinte erro na hora de estampar a mesma no JLABEL:

debug:
nov 26, 2017 10:41:44 PM view.InterfaceProduto buscarKeyPressed
GRAVE: null
javax.imageio.IIOException: Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xac 0xed
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:620)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:347)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:492)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:613)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1070)
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:1050)
    at view.InterfaceProduto.buscarKeyPressed(InterfaceProduto.java:542)
    at view.InterfaceProduto.access$600(InterfaceProduto.java:63)
    at view.InterfaceProduto$8.keyPressed(InterfaceProduto.java:301)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Component.java:6491)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2832)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

CONSTRUÍDO COM SUCESSO (tempo total: 18 segundos)

Gostaria de saber o que posso ter errado...ja fiz testes de saída com o PrintLN e volta caracteres, o que significa que há imagem salva no banco!